# How to draw Distance Poly-line between cities with Google Map API

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I am facing problem that I have to search particular city then searched city should be displayed on MAP as well as other nearest city should be displayed with distance line. Please help me out with code.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxs&libraries=places"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var geocoder;
        function InitializeMap() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions =
            {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        }
        function FindLocaiton(lat, lng, searchedcity, searchedcountry) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            InitializeMap();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            map.setCenter(latlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png',
                position: latlng
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: 'Location info:Location <br/>Country Name:'+ searchedcountry +'<br/>City: '+searchedcity+''
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                // Calling the open method of the infoWindow 
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            return false;
       }
        window.onload = InitializeMap;

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInputArea" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Search" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan ="2">
                <div id ="map" style="height: 253px" ></div></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Further, do I need to create city mapping at my end or should I get nearby cities from Google Map API with given distance?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't share your API key to others.

Comment: Key edited away. Other than that see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple